# Issue with building JSON format. Choose between dict and collections?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pyodbc, defaultdict

I'm building json format and the expected is as below:

```
{   
 accounts:[   {
      "acctnum": "acct1",
      "key2":"value2"
      "key3": []
      "summary" : {
          //nested dict
      }
    }

   ]  //if we have 1 account for given customer     
}
```

If we have more than one account for customer:

```
{   
 accounts:[   {
      "acctnum": "acct1",   // for acct1
      "key2":"value2"
      "key3": []
      "summary" : {
          //nested dict
      }
    },
    {
        "acctnum": "acct2",   //for acct2
        "key2":"value3"
        "key3": []
        "summary" : {
            //nested dict
        }
      }  
    ]       
}
```

After building the dictionary with required attributes for **acct1**, my code towards end is (and have question if I should be using collections module):

```
acctlist = []
acctlist = results  //results is dict for acct1 (with nested dict)
print(acctlist)
accounts  = {}
accounts["accounts"] = acctlist
j = json.dumps(accounts, indent=4)
print(j)
```

But the actual json format comes out as:

```
{   
 accounts: {
      "acctnum": "acct1",
      "key2":"value2"
      "key3": []
      "summary1" : {
          //nested dict
      }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print statement likely answers your question.  Is it a list?

```
acctlist = []
acctlist = results  //results is dict for acct1 (with nested dict)
print(acctlist)
```

I suspect you meant to do `acctlist.append(results)`

Comment: Ops you are correct @Cireo. It is a list and acctlist.append(results) is what I intend to do. So if I have mutiple accts for customer, in that case I would initialize the results = {} , outside the loop (which would run for each acct) ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to have this code properly isolated from the outer loop if you were re-using it for multiple accounts